# SQL Server : IF null Replace with other column data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, numbers, max

I'm really new to SQL Server. I want to replace a null column with another column's data in the same table.

```
Declare @ref As mgr.gl_jlhdr.ref_no
Declare @P_no As mgr.gl_jlhdr.jlno

IF ref = Null
Then ref = P_no
end if
```

Please help.

I get an error

> The type name 'mgr.gl_jlhdr.ref_no' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 1.

What I want is to replace a null value column with other column data.

Example

if `reference_no` is null, I want it to use `Product_no` data.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: what is want is to replace a null value column with other column data. example if reference_no is null, i want it to use Product_no data.

Comment: There are a lot of errors in that code. First, you need to 'declare' as a type (e.g. INT). Second, you need to include the '@' when referencing the variables later. Third, the `If... then... end if` syntax is not SQL. Fourth, `IF @ref = Null` is never going to work: you'd need to use `IS NULL`. Nulls are tricky, there are a whole bunch of functions devoted specifically to working around them (`COALESCE`, `ISNULL`, `IS NULL`) - you really need to get to grips with all of these ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a query, you would do this with `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(reference_no, product_no)
from mgr.gl_jlhdr;
```

Comment: In SQL-Server, I'd be more likely to use `ISNULL`, but the principle is the same.

Comment: @MikeK . . . `COALESCE()` is the ANSI standard and can take more than two arguments.  Under some circumstances, `ISNULL()` is a better choice -- it only evaluates the first argument once, which is better if it is a complex expression such as a subquery.